# Why elements aren't aligned after changing the checkbox?

Tags: html, css

Here's the problem. My checkbox was default one and I changed it by deleting the default styles with: `-webkit-appearance: none;`. But what happened after, you can see in the fiddle.

Somewhy, it's isn't aligned anymore. Tried to use `vertical-align: middle` or `text-align:center`, but didn't helped.

Why did it even happened and how to fix it?

```css
.more-dropdown-price {
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.more-dropdown-checkbox {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #92aabb;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    background-color: #3180D8;
}


.dropdown-items:hover {
    background-color: #87CEFA;
}
```

```html
 <div class="more-dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-items">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="more-dropdown-checkbox"> Foo <span class="more-dropdown-price"> 155$ </span>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-items">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="more-dropdown-checkbox"> Bar <span class="more-dropdown-price"> 15$ </span>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding the following to your `.dropdown-item` class:

```
.dropdown-item{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Then the prices `float: right;` doesn't work. It appears next to name.

Comment: if you add ```justify-content: space-between``` or ```justify-content: space-around``` to my code above, does it achieve the effect you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to input.

```css
.more-dropdown-price {
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.more-dropdown-checkbox {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #92aabb;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    background-color: #3180D8;
}


.dropdown-items:hover {
    background-color: #87CEFA;
}
```

```html
 <div class="more-dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-items">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="more-dropdown-checkbox"> Foo <span class="more-dropdown-price"> 155$ </span>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-items">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="more-dropdown-checkbox"> Bar <span class="more-dropdown-price"> 15$ </span>
                </div>
```

Comment: It's either not exactly equal. Prices are a little higher.

Answer (score -1):

try something like this:

```
.dropdown-items:hover {
background-color: #87CEFA;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
align-content: center;
```

}

But I think you should align to the left because the elements have different number of letters so they are never aligned